# MenuItem icon returns collection

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I have a following code, it all works fine:

```
    <Image x:Key="Icons" x:Shared="false"
     Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" Height="16px" Width="16px"/>

    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem" >
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{StaticResource Icons}"/>            
    </Style>
```

But I have to load xaml from external source and `WPF` has a bug that does not allow `x:Shared=` in that case. So I made Resource dictionary with `x:Name=Icons` that is compiled internally (Action is database table that has string property Icon and there is path to the Icon):

```
<Image x:Key="Icons" x:Shared="False"
     Source="{Binding Path=Action.Icon}" Height="16px" Width="16px"/>
```

and the code now looks

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="IkoniceDict" Source="/MVVM_App;component/View/iconimage.xaml"/>
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Icons}}"/>
```

Problem is that now I get (collection) instead of image:

[image]

Need help, please!

Comment: You should combine the Headers, Icons, Children and IsEnabled in One Class Model, and Bind the Item Properties to the Model.

Comment: Try setting the Path:  <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{Binding Path=Icon, Source={StaticResource Icons}}"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not specify a key when loading a resource dictionary into the control.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/MVVM_App;component/View/iconimage.xaml"/>
```

### Edit

I guess I'm not clear enough. The above only works if you have nothing but this in that single `<SomeControl.Resources>` tag.

```
<SomeControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MVVM_App;component/View/iconimage.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyleKey" .............>
    </Style>
</SomeControl.Resources>
```

The `Resources` is a `ResourceDictionary` type. All entries must have an `x:Key`. If you assign an `x:Key` to an `ResourceDictionary` inside `Resources` tag, you are putting a dictionary inside dictionary. That is why you need to use `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionary` to tell the XAML parser to merge the contents of iconimage.xaml in.

Comment: Got message "Each dictionary entry must have an asociated key", so key is mandatory.

Comment: @Branko where did you put this in?

Comment: @Branko Updated. Original solution only works if you don't have other stuff in the same Resources tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should set the **Path** property for your **Binding** (set it to "Source"):

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{Binding Path=Source, Source={StaticResource Icons}}"/>
```

When the **path** is not specified, the **default is to bind to the entire object** (in your case the collection of icons).

[Msdn Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Now I lost collection too and it's all empty.

Comment: @Branko Set Path to "Source": Value="{Binding Path=Source, Source={StaticResource Icons}}"?